# Why workflow engine of Jenkins is designed in a continuation passing style way?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I know workflow of Jenkins provides both CPS and NonCPS models, i wonder what's the difference between them, and how Jenkinsfile is resolved in a CPS way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of CPS is that a pipeline execution can be resumed after a Jenkins master restart.

During the execution of a pipeline, every single step executed by an agent is stored on the master (IIRC it was like 4 calls to the master per step).

As CPS is not compatible with all Groovy features, you sometimes have to disable it (or if you have a simple loop etc. and want to avoid the overhead introduced by CPS).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think i understand why pipeline is designed in CPS. But i still feel confused about how Jenkinsfiles are resolved. Was Jenkinsfile resolved and stored in a ArrayList first, and then Jenkins iterates the ArrayList to distribute all steps? Any docs about this will be helpful, thank you again!

Comment: I don't think it's like an ArrayList. It's code, which is executed, a so-called "Domain Specific Language" (DSL).

Comment: Alright...Maybe I should look into Gradle to understand what DSL can do..not much docs for Jenkins.

Comment: This has nothing to do with each other, besides that both tools provide a DSL. Like Chef, Ansible, and thousands of other tools. Read [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) maybe.